# What's up with glowing Naruto?

Tags: naruto

While watching some Naruto fights on YouTube out of context (not seeing previous episodes or movies), I noticed that Naruto now has the ability to (what looks like) catch fire, and give his Nine-Tailed Fox chakra to other people just by touching them.

Now normally, when using his Nine-Tailed Fox chakra, he turns red and stuff, but this time he looked less like a fox, had a robe, and was bright orange instead of red.

I could have sworn I also saw another flaming ninja, but it might have been his clone move.

Anyways, I'd like to know when, how, why, and what this is and how he discovered that power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the [Nine Tailed Fox Cloak](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Nine-Tails_Chakra_Mode) that Naruto learned to control just before/during the Fourth (I believe) Great Shinobi War.

Answer (score 0):

That's actually not Kurama's chakra. Sure Naruto can only enter that mode because he is a Jinchuuriki, but he does so by absorbing Kurama's chakra and then transmuting it into his own chakra signature. What we are seeing is Naruto's chakra mixed with Kurama's.

Naruto's chakra is described as bright and orange. Kurama's chakra is neither bright nor orange; it's dark red.

Moreover, Naruto's ancestor had the same cloak despite not being a Jinchuuriki